# Problem in fread and fwrite in my bank record management program

Tags: c, file, fwrite, fread

I'm doing my bank record management system project and I'm facing problem in reading from file. My file name is "name_of_the_user.txt" and opened in wb+ mode. I've a structure which have some fields such as name, address, *money*, etc. I've been trying to deposit and withdraw from account by reading the data into structure BMS u1 and then doing following functions, but I think reading into this structures leads to corruption of file and some garbage value. Please help.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <windows.h>
void main_menu(char*);
void update_acc(char *);
// void deposit( char *);
// void withdrawl( char *);

struct BMS
{
    char name[20];
    char mailid[20];
    unsigned long long contact;
    unsigned long long adhar;
    int date, year, month;
    char address[100];
    char password[15];
    int money;
};
struct balance{
    char namefrom[20];
    char nameto[20];
    long int money;
};
void gotoxy(int x, int y)
{
    COORD c;
    c.X = x;
    c.Y = y;

    SetConsoleCursorPosition(
        GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), c);
}
void view_acc(char username[])
{
    FILE *fp;
    struct BMS u1;
    char filename[20];
    strcpy(filename, username);
    fp = fopen(strcat(filename, ".bin"), "rb");
    if(fp==NULL){
        printf("Error viewing account details.");
    }
    fread(&u1, sizeof(u1), 1, fp);
    printf("%s\n", u1.name);
    printf("%llu\n", u1.contact);
    printf("%llu\n", u1.adhar);
    
    printf("%d - %d - %d\n", u1.date, u1.month, u1.year);
    printf("%s\n", u1.address);
    printf("%s\n", u1.mailid);
    printf("Balance : %d\n", u1.money);
    fclose(fp);
}
void create_acc()
{
    system("cls");
    FILE *fp;
    struct BMS u1;
    int k=0;
    char ch1, temp, filename[20];
    scanf("%c",&temp);
    u1.money = 0;
    printf("\t\t\tFill in the details \n");
    printf("Name of account holder: ");
    scanf("%[^\n]", &u1.name);
    printf("Enter DOB : ");
    printf("Date : ");
    scanf("%d" , &u1.date);
    printf("\nMonth : ");
    scanf("%d", &u1.month);
    printf("\nYear : ");
    scanf("%d", &u1.year);
    printf("Enter your mobile number : ");
    scanf("%llu", &u1.contact);
    printf("Enter your Aadhar ID : ");
    scanf("%llu", &u1.adhar);
    scanf("%c",&temp);
    printf("Enter user email : ");
    scanf("%[^\n]", &u1.mailid);
    scanf("%c",&temp);
    printf("Enter Your Address : ");
    scanf("%[^\n]", &u1.address);
    printf("Create PIN : ");
    for(k=0; k<15; k++)
     {
             ch1 = getch();
             u1.password[k]=ch1;
      
             if(ch1!=13 && ch1!=8)     
                   printf("*");
             if(ch1 == 13)
                   break;
      }
      u1.password[k]='\0';
      printf("\nYour created PIN is : ");
      for(k=0; k<strlen(u1.password); k++){
          printf("%c", u1.password[k]);
      }
    printf("\nYour Account has beem succesfully added to our system. Please remember your created PIN to acces your account.\n\n");
    strcpy(filename, u1.name);
    fp = fopen(strcat(filename, ".bin"), "ab");
    fwrite(&u1, sizeof(u1),1, fp);
    fclose(fp);
}
void login(){
    system("cls");
    FILE *fp;
    struct BMS u1;
    char name[20], temp, password[15],ch1, filename[20];
    int i, j, k;
    scanf("%c",&temp);
    printf("Enter your name : ");
    scanf("%[^\n]", &name);
    scanf("%c",&temp);
    printf("Enter your PIN : ");
    scanf("%s", &password);
    strcpy(filename, name);
    fp = fopen(strcat(filename, ".bin"),"rb");
    if(fp==NULL){
        printf("No account found.");
    }
    fread(&u1, sizeof(u1), 1, fp);
    
    if(!strcmp(password, u1.password)){
        printf("Login succesful.");
        fclose(fp);
        main_menu(name);
    }
    else {
        printf("Login failed wrong password.");
        fclose(fp);
    }
}
void transaction(char username[])
{
    system("cls");
    FILE *fp, *fp1, *fm;
    struct BMS u1;
    struct balance b1;
    char userfrom[20], userto[20],username1, username2, temp;
    // strcpy(username1, username);
    scanf("%c", &temp);
    printf("Transfer money to : ");
    scanf("%[^\n]", &userto);
    printf("Enter the amount to be transferred : ");
    scanf("%ld", &b1.money);
    // fp1 = fopen(strcat(username1, ".txt"), )
    strcpy(userfrom, username);
    strcpy(username, userto);
    fp = fopen(strcat(username, ".bin"), "rb");
    fm = fopen("money.bin", "ab");
    while (fread(&u1, sizeof(u1), 1, fp))
    {
        if (strcmp(userto, u1.name) == 0) {
            strcpy(b1.nameto, u1.name);
            strcpy(b1.namefrom, userfrom);
        }
    }
    fwrite(&b1, sizeof(b1), 1, fm);
    fclose(fm);
    fclose(fp);

}
void viewbalance(char username[]){
    system("cls");  
    FILE *fm;
    struct balance b1;
    char ch;
    int i=1 , money=0;
    fm = fopen("money.bin", "rb");

    int k = 5, l = 10;
    int m = 30, n = 10;
    int u = 60, v = 10;

    gotoxy(30, 2);
    printf("==== BALANCE DASHBOARD ====");
    gotoxy(30, 3);
    printf("***************************");
    gotoxy(k, l);
    printf("S NO.");
    gotoxy(m, n);
    printf("TRANSACTION ID");
    gotoxy(u, v);
    printf("AMOUNT");
    while (fread(&b1, sizeof(b1), 1, fm)) {
        if (strcmp(username, b1.nameto) == 0) {
            gotoxy(k, ++l);
            printf("%d", i);
            i++;
            gotoxy(m, ++n);
            printf("%s", b1.namefrom);

            gotoxy(u, ++v);
            printf("%ld", b1.money);
            money = money + b1.money;
        }
    }
    gotoxy(80, 10);
    printf("TOTAL AMOUNT");

    gotoxy(80, 12);
    printf("%d", money);

    getch();
    fclose(fm);
}
void deposit( char username[]){
    struct BMS u1;
    FILE *fp;
    char filename[20];
    strcpy(filename, username);
    fp = fopen(strcat(filename, ".bin"), "wb+");
    fread(&u1, sizeof(u1),1, fp);
    int amount = 0;
    printf("Enter the amount to be deposited : ");
    scanf("%d", &amount);
    u1.money = u1.money + amount;
    printf("Money succesfully deposited.");
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);
    fwrite(&u1, sizeof(u1),1, fp);
    fclose(fp);
}
void withdrawl( char username[]){
    struct BMS u1;
    FILE *fp;
    char filename[20];
    strcpy(filename, username);
    fp = fopen(strcat(filename, ".bin"), "wb+");
    if(fp==NULL){
        printf("Error");
    }
    printf("%s", u1.name);
    if(fread(&u1, sizeof(u1),1, fp)!=0){
        printf("error");
    }
    printf("%s", u1.name);
    int amount = 0;
    printf("Enter the amount to be withdrawn : ");
    scanf("%d", &amount);
    // fread(&u1, sizeof(u1), 1, fbin
    if(u1.money<amount){
        printf("Not enough money to withdraw.\n");
    }
    else{
        u1.money = u1.money - amount;
        printf("Money succesfully withdrawn.\n");
        fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);
        fwrite(&u1, sizeof(u1),1, fp);
    }
    fclose(fp);
}
void main_menu(char username[]){
    system("cls");
    char username1[20];
    strcpy(username1, username);
    while(1){
        printf("\t\t\t\tWELCOME %s\n", username);
        printf("\t\t\t\t1.View account details\n");
        printf("\t\t\t\t2.Update Account\n");
        printf("\t\t\t\t3.Make a Transaction\n");
        printf("\t\t\t\t4.To view all Transaction\n");
        printf("\t\t\t\t5.Make a Deposit\n");
        printf("\t\t\t\t6.Make a Withdrawl\n");
        printf("\t\t\t\t7.LOG OUT\n");
        int ch;
        printf("Enter your choice : ");
        scanf("%d", &ch);
        if(ch==1){
            view_acc(username1);
        }
        else if(ch==2){
            update_acc(username1);
        }
        else if(ch==3){
            transaction(username1);
        }
        else if(ch==4){
            viewbalance(username1);
        }
        else if(ch==5){
        deposit(username1);
        }
        else if(ch==6){
            withdrawl(username1);
        }
    }
}
void update_acc(char username[]){
    FILE *fp1, *fp2;
    struct BMS u1;
    struct BMS u2;
    int ch, k=0;
    char temp, ch1, filename[20];
    strcpy(filename, username);
    fp1 = fopen(strcat(filename, ".bin"), "rb");
    fp2 = fopen("copy.bin", "ab");
    if(fp1==NULL){
        printf("error updating data!\n");
    }
    printf("Press 1 to update Name.\n");
    printf("Press 2 to update Mobile number.\n");
    printf("Press 3 to update Email id.\n");
    printf("Press 4 to update Address.\n");
    printf("Press 5 to update DOB.\n");
    printf("Press 6 to update password.\n");
    printf("Press 0 to go back\n");
    printf("Enter your choice : ");
    scanf("%d", &ch);
    if(ch==1){
        printf("Please enter your new name : ");
        char name[20];
        scanf("%d", &temp);
        scanf("%[^\n]", &name);
        while(fread(&u1, sizeof(u1), 1, fp1)){
            if(strcmp(u1.name , name)){
                fwrite(&u1, sizeof(u1), 1, fp2);
            }
        }
        strcpy(u2.name , name);
        fwrite(&u2, sizeof(u2), 1, fp2);
        fclose(fp2);
        fclose(fp1);
        int del = remove(filename);
        rename("copy.bin", filename);
        printf("Name succesfully updated.\n");
    }
    else if(ch==2){
        printf("Please enter your new mobile number : ");
        unsigned long long contact;
        scanf("%llu", &contact);
        while(fread(&u1, sizeof(u1), 1, fp1)){
            if(u1.contact != contact){
                fwrite(&u1, sizeof(u1), 1, fp2);
            }
        }
        u2.contact = contact;
        fwrite(&u2, sizeof(u2), 1, fp2);
        fclose(fp2);
        fclose(fp1);
        int del = remove(filename);
        rename("copy.bin", filename);
        printf("Contact succesfully updated.\n");
    }
    else if(ch==3){
        printf("Please enter your new mail id : ");
        scanf("%d", &temp);
        char mailid[20];
        scanf("%[^\n]", &mailid);
        while(fread(&u1, sizeof(u1), 1, fp1)){
            if(strcmp(u1.mailid , mailid)){
                fwrite(&u1, sizeof(u1), 1, fp2);
            }
        }
        strcpy(u2.mailid , mailid);
        fwrite(&u2, sizeof(u2), 1, fp2);
        fclose(fp2);
        fclose(fp1);
        int del = remove(filename);
        rename("copy.bin", filename);
        printf("Email succesfully updated.\n");
    }
    else if(ch==4){
        printf("Please enter your new address : ");
        scanf("%d", &temp);
        char address[100];
        scanf("%[^\n]", &address);
        while(fread(&u1, sizeof(u1), 1, fp1)){
            if(strcmp(u1.address , address)){
                fwrite(&u1, sizeof(u1), 1, fp2);
            }
        }
        strcpy(u2.address , address);
        fwrite(&u2, sizeof(u2), 1, fp2);
        fclose(fp2);
        fclose(fp1);
        int del = remove(filename);
        rename("copy.bin", filename);
        printf("Address succesfully updated.\n");
    }
    else if(ch==5){
        printf("Enter your new DOB : ");
        int date, month, year;
        printf("Date : ");
        scanf("%d" , &date);
        printf("\nMonth : ");
        scanf("%d", &month);
        printf("\nYear : ");
        scanf("%d", &year);
       while(fread(&u1, sizeof(u1), 1, fp1)){
            if(u1.date != date || u1.month != month || u1.year != year){
                fwrite(&u1, sizeof(u1), 1, fp2);
            }
        }
        u2.date = date;
        u2.month = month;
        u2.year = year;

        fwrite(&u2, sizeof(u2), 1, fp2);
        fclose(fp2);
        fclose(fp1);
        int del = remove(filename);
        rename("copy.bin", filename);
        printf("DOB succesfully updated.\n");
    }
    else if(ch==6){
        printf("Enter your new PIN : ");
        char password[15];
        for(k=0; k<15; k++){
            ch1 = getch();
            password[k]=ch1;
            if(ch1!=13 && ch1!=8)     
                printf("*");
            if(ch1 == 13)
                break;
        }
        password[k]='\0';
        printf("\nYour new created PIN is : ");
        for(k=0; k<strlen(password); k++){
            printf("%c", password[k]);
        }
        while(fread(&u1, sizeof(u1), 1, fp1)){
            if(strcmp(u1.password , password)){
                fwrite(&u1, sizeof(u1), 1, fp2);
            }
        }
        strcpy(u2.password , password);
        fwrite(&u2, sizeof(u2), 1, fp2);
        fclose(fp2);
        fclose(fp1);
        int del = remove(filename);
        rename("copy.bin", filename);
        printf("\nPassword succesfully updated.\n");
    }
    else if(ch==0){
        fclose(fp1);
        fclose(fp2);
    }
    
}
// void deposit( char username[]){
//     struct BMS u1;
//     FILE *fp;
//     char filename[20];
//     strcpy(filename, username);
//     fp = fopen(strcat(filename, ".txt"), "w+");
//     fread(&u1, sizeof(u1),1, fp);
//     int amount = 0;
//     printf("Enter the amount to be deposited : ");
//     scanf("%d", &amount);
//     u1.money = u1.money + amount;
//     printf("Money succesfully deposited.");
//     fwrite(&u1, sizeof(u1),1, fp);
//     fclose(fp);
// }
// void withdrawl( char username[]){
//     struct BMS u1;
//     FILE *fp;
//     char filename[20];
//     strcpy(filename, username);
//     fp = fopen(strcat(filename, ".txt"), "w+");
//     fread(&u1, sizeof(u1),1, fp);
//     int amount = 0;
//     printf("Enter the amount to be withdrawn : ");
//     scanf("%d", &amount);
//     fread(&u1, sizeof(u1), 1, fp);
//     if(u1.money<amount){
//         printf("Not enough money to withdraw.");
//     }
//     else{
//         u1.money = u1.money - amount;
//         printf("Money succesfully withdrawn.");
//         fwrite(&u1, sizeof(u1),1, fp);
//     }
    
//     fclose(fp);
// }
int main()
{
    system("cls");
    struct BMS u1[N];
    int choice;
    int i = 0;
    while (5)
    {
        printf("\t\t\t\tWELCOME TO THE BANK MANAGEMENT SYSTEM\n");
        printf("\t\t\t\t1.Create new account\n");
        printf("\t\t\t\t2.Login into existing account\n");
        printf("\t\t\t\t6.Exit\n");
        printf("\nEnter Your Choice : ");
        scanf("%d", &choice);
        if (choice == 1)
        {
            create_acc();
        }
        else if (choice == 2)
        {
            login();
        }
        else if (choice == 6){

        }
    }
    //printf("Thanks For Coming !!");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Corrupted... how? Please, include an example of the original file, the main() issuing your functions and how it looks the file after the "corruption".

Comment: There are other potential problems, depending on how your `BMS` structure is defined. Show complete code.

Comment: Ive uploaded the whole code

Answer (score 0):

You need to seek to the beginning of the file before you write. Otherwise it writes the updated record at the place where you left off reading, instead of overwriting the original record.

```
void deposit( char username[]){
    struct BMS u1;
    FILE *fp;
    char filename[20];
    strcpy(filename, username);
    fp = fopen(strcat(filename, ".txt"), "wb+");
    fread(&u1, sizeof(u1),1, fp);
    int amount = 0;
    printf("Enter the amount to be deposited : ");
    scanf("%d", &amount);
    u1.money = u1.money + amount;
    printf("Money succesfully deposited.");
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);
    fwrite(&u1, sizeof(u1),1, fp);
    fclose(fp);
}
```

Comment: its still not working file is still getting corrupted.

Comment: The file is named `.txt`, but reading into a struct expects a binary file. Is it a text or binary file?

Comment: I changed it to **.bin** file too it's not working.

Comment: The filename isn't relevant, what is the intended contents?

Comment: How do you know you're getting garbage values?

Comment: I am printing detail of account created and its printing garbage value after invoking deposit function, and i also tried printing details such as u1.money(gives some garbage value) and u1.name(prints nothing).

Comment: What is in the original file before you call the function? Is it a text file or a binary file?

Comment: I suspect it's a text file, not a binary file, so you should be using `fscanf()` and `fprintf()` to read and write.

Comment: ok I'll try that,